# WPF Binding inner DataGrid to different Data-Object

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I want to bind an nested `DataGrid` (`RowDetailsTemplate`) to different data-object with resp. to the data-object for the outer `DataGrid`.

It works properly for the outer object "Outer", but how can I access the inner data object "Inner".

The xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowModel x:Key="vm"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="grdMain" Height="170" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagridOuter"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Outer}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Height="170">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Outer"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                MinWidth="150"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Name="datagridInner"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=DataContext.Inner}"
                          Height="50"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inner"
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                            MinWidth="150"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Item ( string name_ )
    {
        this.Name = name_;
    }
} //eoClass
```

The MainWindowModel class:

```
class MainWindowModel : Notifier
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> outer;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Outer
    {
        get { return this.outer; }
        set
        {
            this.outer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( "Outer" );
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> inner;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Inner
    {
        get { return this.inner; }
        set
        {
            this.inner = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( "Inner" );
        }
    }
} //eoClass
```

Comment: I got a little bit stucked with what you are asking, because for me it looks like your model did not fit/represents your needs. Could it be possible that you want to bind some kind of ` Outer0 { Inner01, Inner02, Inner03 }, Outer1 { Inner11, Inner12, Inner13, ... } ...` instead of { Outer0, Outer1 } and { Inner01, Inner02, Inner03,  Inner11, Inner12, Inner13, ...  }

Comment: From the MainWindowModel view there is **no coupling between the two collections** Inner and Outer. The coupling is done in the underlaying datamodel. The "Inner" collection is updated in the underlaying datamodel so that the "Inner" collection corresponds to the actual seleted data of the "Outer" collection. My question is, how to apply the binding of the details-datagrid and the "Inner" collection.

Comment: Have you tested the first part of my Answer. Change the binding of the ItemSource to `ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=grdMain, Path=DataContext.Inner}"`

Answer (score 0):

Looking for an ancestor of the type `Grid` can be really annoying, because most controls containing some nested `Grid`s. I personally try to avoid this.

For example when you look at the VisualLiveTree of your DataGrid you will find some occurrences:

[image: The VisualLiveTree of your <code>DataGrid</code>]

The reason why you did not get your binding, is that [`FindAncestor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode(v=vs.110).aspx) will start at your binding target and will search upward all parents in the VisualTree until it finds the first `Grid`. And your `grdMain` is probably the last in this chain.

---

So your are already had given your `Grid` a name, just so use it.
Changing your inner `ItemSource` binding from:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=DataContext.Inner}"
```

to:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=grdMain, Path=DataContext.Inner}"
```

will do the trick. It will look for the requested binding at the element specified with the name `grdMain`.

---

*Based on your comment, I rolled back my answer, to fit your needs.*

> From the MainWindowModel view there is no coupling between the two collections Inner and Outer. The coupling is done in the underlaying datamodel. The "Inner" collection is updated in the underlaying datamodel so that the "Inner" collection corresponds to the actual seleted data of the "Outer" collection. My question is, how to apply the binding of the details-datagrid and the "Inner" collection.

Comment: Your first solution fits my requirements. It works. I thought that I already had tried to address ElementName=grdMain, but most likely I have made other mistakes with binding parameters. You helped me get out of that circle. Besides: Outer collection is from database and Inner collection is received as measured signals from the process.

Comment: Forgot to mention for reader: Martin's first solution: <... ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=grdMain, Path=DataContext.Inner}" ../>

Comment: @Ruebezaehler: I rolled back to my previous solution, to shorten things up. _If my answer really fits your needs allow me to link you to:_ [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If somebody wants to see my extended answer please look in the history and feel free to rollback the rollback.

Comment: Feel free to shorten/modify or link your answer. Can I do something for your reputation (voting)? If yes, could you please tell me where?

Comment: @Ruebezaehler: You can mark this as answer and/or vote if it really helps you but you are not committed to do this. Just take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) & [Accepting Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)